# Get Gmail inbox as HTML format

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gmail, arrays

i have this code;

```
 Message message = pop3Client.GetMessage(%count);
 MessagePart messagePart = message.MessagePart.MessageParts[0];

 DateLiteral.Text = message.Headers.Date;   
 FromLiteral.Text = message.Headers.From.Address;
 SubjectLiteral.Text = message.Headers.Subject;
 BodyLiteral.Text =messagePart.BodyEncoding.GetString(messagePart.Body)
```

The Code get the gmail inbox information, date,from who sent the email, subject and body.The email body receive as a byte[] and convert into string.Instead of byte, I want to receive it as HTML format. or may can I convert the byte into HTML Format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the gmail inbox in actual format you can use FindFirstHtmlVersion() then you need to decode it ............GetString().

[go to this link for more info](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/examples.php)